# How do custom URL schemes work with the `UILaunchImages` key in iOS7?

Tags: ios, ios7

The only Apple documentation I can find for ["Providing Launch Images for Custom URL Schemes"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12) only mentions a naming scheme based on the `UILaunchImageFile` key.  However, the [documentation for `UILaunchImages`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW28) says:

> If this key is present, iOS 7 uses it exclusively to obtain launch images. The system does not fall back to the older naming conventions used prior to iOS 7.

As far as I can see, it doesn't say anything about how to tell iOS 7 to use a custom launch image for a custom URL scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just experimenting with the simulator, I see that launch images using the `UILaunchImageFile` custom url scheme format `<basename>-<url_scheme><scale_modifier><device_modifier>.png` appear to get picked up just fine on iOS 7 despite the presence of a competing `UILaunchImages` file.  This seems to slightly contradict the part of the documentation that says the system won't fall back on older naming conventions, but it works well enough for me.  The big limitation of this approach is that for custom URL schemes I have to use the same launch image for both iOS 6 and iOS 7.